# cannot access programmatically a popup in side listbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, popup

I have a list box and I want a popup control to popup when each row onclicked event I put pop in .xmal but I can't change the isopened="true" programmatically in .cs file here is my .xmal looks like

```
<ListView Name="listView1" Height="306" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="982,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="370" SelectionChanged="listView1_SelectionChanged" >


    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
              <Setter Property="Height" Value="58" />
         </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
         <Grid Name="g2">
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>                            
         <Label Name="lblitemname" Grid.Row="0" Content="Item Name" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Medium" Margin="40,0,0,0" FontFamily="Baskerville Old Face" FontStyle="Italic"/>

         <Label Name="lblx" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="11" Content="x" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="50,0,0,-5"/>

         <Label Name="lblprice" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="11" Content="50.00" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="60,0,0,-5"/>

         <Label Name="lblqty" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="11" Content="5" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="40,0,0,-5"/>

         <Label Name="lbltotip" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="11" Content="Rs. 250.00" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="250,0,0,-5"/>

         <!--This is popup start-->
         <StackPanel Margin="50,0,0,0">
            <Popup Name="editpop" PopupAnimation="Slide" AllowsTransparency="True" HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="0" Placement="Right">

             <Canvas Width="600" Height="250">                                        
             <TextBlock Canvas.Left="75"
                  Canvas.Top="28"
                   Width="500"
                   Height="200"
                   Text="Please Enter Your Passcode To Log In"
                   TextWrapping="Wrapwithoverflow"
                   FontSize="20"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="White"
                   />


                  <PasswordBox Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="70" Name="txtpwd" Grid.Row="3"  Height="60" Width="380"   FontWeight="Bold"  />
                    </Canvas>
                   </Popup>
                </StackPanel>
                <!--This is popup end-->

            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit difficult to fully understand your problem from the one sentence that you used to explain it. However, I think that you just need a way to access the `Popup` control from your `DataTemplate`. To find out how you can do this, please read the [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Please let me know if I have misunderstood your problem and if I have, then can you please explain it better.

Comment: thank you  this methord didn't work so I did it this way http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahakgupta/popup-control-in-wpf/ by the way thank you again for trying to help me